# Need a Regular expression to validate comments in the webpage

Tags: c#, regex

Need a regular expression to check if webpage has special characters in the comments field.
Comments should only have characters,numbers and  @ = - ' " . i inside the comments.
I am using C#.net to check it

THis is the code I have and it does not work

```
 if (!Regex.IsMatch(comments.Text,@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]$"))
 {
     lblError.Text = "Please Check your Comment.";
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: go to http://www.regexlib.com/

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to use this to prevent sql injection.  If so, you're going about it completely wrong.

Comment: @Joel: No; he's allowing both `'` and `"`.  However, he still shouldn't be doing this; comments should be free-form.

Comment: any advice to prevent cross site scripting

Comment: our website is failing  the security test by the client.So i need to do validation to correct this.Let meknow if I there is anything I can do to prevent this.

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  Please provide more details.

Comment: you also forgot to include whitespace as a valid input.

Comment: *pokes self with a stick* Nevermind the forgetting to include whitespace comment.  I see it in your code, but it wasn't in the requirements (which is what I was looking at).  I blame lack of sleep which I am now going to go remedy

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9@=\-'"]+
```

Comment: In addition to meeting the stated requirements, this is the only answer that correctly escapes the hyphen.  It looks the OP was trying to do that by surrounding it with single-quotes (`'-'`).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the comment contains only one character because of the interval between `^` and `$`. Just remove them and if I remember correctly what Regex.IsMatch does, it should work.

`Regex.IsMatch(comments.Text,@"[^a-zA-Z''-'\s]")`

On a side note, perhaps you should allow numbers, too.

Oh, and I should note that it will return true if any other character than those indicated is found.

Comment: if any character is found which is not in the list then it should retrun false and throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be something like @"[^\w\s''-'@\"]"

\w gives you the alphabetic characters (including accented character), numeric characters and the underscore

\s gives you the whitespace

(I escaped the ", but it may or may not be needed.  It's a little after 3am and I'm a little fuzzy, so you may need to play with that a bit...)

Comment: The quotation mark doesn't need to be escaped for the regex compiler, but it does for the C# compiler.  For that you use `""`, not `\"`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on that.  Like I said, it was 3am and I was basically dead in my chair